# jQuery append makes browser automatically scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a newsfeed-like div where the user scrolls down the page to the bottom, then more elements are added. The initial elements are also loaded this way. However, when more elements are loaded, regardless if it's the first bunch or later on after scrolling down, the page jumps around. How can I stop this?

Code probably won't help explaining, but here's some regardless:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("/get_elements", function( data ) {
        $("#newsfeed").append(data);
    });
    //window.scrollTo(0,0); 
});
```

After that code executes, the document height goes from 800px or so to maybe 5000px. The browser is also randomly scrolled down 2000-3000 pixels. However, since nothing has been done by the user, it should still be at the top.

HTML AS REQUESTED:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="newsfeed">

</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Mind sharing your HTML?

Comment: @DanWilson Not much in it, but added

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how that would happen. If you're appending content then the scroll position should be retained. What does your rendered page look like (screen cap)?